# Issue with Django Web Tutorial

Tags: python, django

I am extremely new to programming. I searched and found a few similar threads here, though unfortunately the answers in those threads didn't seem to fix my own issue.

**Problem**

I am working my way through the Django tutorials, and I am on the third tutorial: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/

I'm not sure if this matters, but I am working on a Macintosh w/ Mavericks.

The root directory in which I am working is 'Test2'. The directory structure is:

/Users/me/src/collact/collact/test2/

Within 'test2', and per the previous two tutorials, I have '/polls' and '/templates' folders.

My polls/views.py file has the following text:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

My polls/urls.py file has the following text:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Finally, in /test2/, I have a urls python file as well (.py). It has the text:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

As far as I can tell, this is what the tutorial prescribes. Unfortunately, when I run the server using: **python manage.py runserver**, the website gives me an error/404 message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:
GET Request
URL: http://localhost:8000/polls/ Using the URLconf defined in
test2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: ^admin/
The current URL, polls/, didn't match any of these. You're seeing this
error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file.
Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? I know that this is a really stupid question, but I have been trying to figure it out for the past day or two, and unfortunately I'm just not familiar enough with programming to solve this on my own.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your urls configs. Is it possible that you didn't add polls to the INSTALLED_APPS collection in your settings.py file in the first page of the tutorial?

Comment: Are you saying your main urls.py is in the base directory of the app?

Comment: Hi Dylrei - Yes, I do have polls included in the settings.py file. Interestingly, the settings file is in test2/test2/settings.py

Comment: Hey Daniel - yes, there are TWO urls.py files. One of them is in the base directory, while the other is in the polls directory.

Comment: Works for me.
Stupid question, but did you have all your files saved ?

Comment: @Jacob Try moving your `settings.py` up one directory so it's in `test2/settings.py`.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server? Sometimes this is needed for django to find newly created files

Comment: Hi everyone - thank you for the help. @Andrew_Lvov, I have saved the files, yes. Unfortunately, no change!

Comment: @aus_lacy, I tried doing that, but unfortunately the server won't start when I move settings.py up a directory.

Comment: And @user1631075 - Yep, I tried restarting (several times). Unfortunately, no change :(

Comment: Is that the whole error message you got? If it is, it seems that "^/polls" isn't being checked. Could you post your settings.py file?